# Is it possible to transform a script calling a DLL with ctypes into an executable using cx_Freeze and how can I do it?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

[picture of all the file I need to make my motor works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2eu3.png)

I have a python script which call a DLL from LabVIEW that I created to control a motor and everything work perfectly but I want to transform my script in a .exe file but I don't know how to call an external DLL using cx_freeze

This is my main script with how I call the DLL file :

```
 lvdll = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary("duty_final_servo.dll")
add = lvdll.PWM_control_servo
add.argtypes = [ct.c_double, ct.c_int, np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype = 
np.float64), ct.c_int]
add.restype = ct.c_double
tab=np.asarray(position_vect)
res = add(step_time_milli, number_sample, tab, number_sample)
libHandle = lvdll._handle
del lvdll
ct.windll.kernel32.FreeLibrary(libHandle)
```

Comment: main application = other script = `Graphical_interface_duty_V16_labview.py` if I understand your code correctly. Where do you actually need to use `duty_final.dll`, in the main application `Graphical_interface_duty_V16_labview.py` or in the setup script `setup.py`? Apparently you are using it in the setup script, this is what I don't understand.

Comment: If you don't use clr in your main script so you don't need to use it in the .exe either. What you need to fix is ctypes and your DLL not included properly by cx_Freeze, this has nothing to do with pythonnet/clr then. If you launch your exe from a cmd prompt, do you see any error message beside the motor not moving?

Comment: All right so please edit your post to make it correspond to your actual question. Remove everything regarding clr or pythonnet from your post and from your `setup.py`. Please also remove those of the above comments which are irrelevant to your actual question (I've done that with my comments already).

Comment: Back to your question: it is possible to transform a script calling a DLL with ctypes into an executable using cx_Freeze, I've done that. You basically need to let cx_Freeze include the DLL and all its dependencies using the `include_files` option in the setup script. But the DLL needs to be placed where the executable looks for it (or the executable told to look at the right place), and all dependencies of the DLL need to be included as well and the DLL needs to be able to find them.

Comment: The right place depends a bit on how you call the DLL from your main script, please add that part of your main script to your question (see also how to provide a [example]).

Comment: And how does the DLL itself communicate with the motor? Does it have further dependencies?

Comment: I edit my post and I'll try to test by adding all the files in includefiles

Comment: I put all my files concerning my DLL on includesfiles and all this file are copying in the same folder as the one of my .exe but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try to make a copy of all these files into the `lib` subdirectory as well (manually) after building the .exe.

Comment: What is the lib subdirectory ?

Comment: Because I already copy all this file in the folder of my .exe after building it

Comment: Which version of cx_Freeze are you using? If you use 5.1.1 (the current version), the build directory = the folder of your .exe has a `lib` subdirectory, all python packages get included into there.

Comment: Ah yes I have it I'll try it

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: In your code you call the DLL via `duty_final_servo.dll` but in the picture the DLL is named `duty_final.dll`. This cannot work--or is it a mistake in your post?

Comment: sorry it's a mistake of the post

Comment: but when i just launch my python script everything work perfectly

Comment: You need to debug your exe step by step by adding print statements or a simple message method to your DLL which you call from the main script, I don't see any other method. Probably some dependency of ctypes (or of numpy?) is missing, but what I don't understand is why you don't get any error. Does your exe run completely until the end without error (beside the fact that the motor does not move)?

Comment: No my .exe just block when it's the time to make the motor moving and then it just stay blocked at this step but I don't have any errors

Comment: Do you have any other ideas ? Otherwise I'll give up

Comment: You could add logging to your DLL to see exactly which instruction is blocking. But it looks like the communication chain from your DLL to the motor (or the other way round?) is not working. Try to understand which components are involved and which ones work or don't work. Try to replace your DLL by a simpler one with just a simple print statement, no motor control.

Comment: So I tried to do a DLL with a simple thing which was making just an addition between 2 numbers but it doesn't work. So I think the connection between LabVIEW and Python is not possible to do.